# Why am I unable to add any margins or padding to the elements inside this section tag? (Using Tailwind)

Tags: html, tailwind-css

Here is my current code:
`

```
<section id="introduction" class="bg-gradient-to-bl from-cyan-500 via-teal-400 to-blue-500 h-[700px]">
           <div class="w-[450px] flex flex-col">
                <h1 class="text-6xl font-semibold text-white leading-[75px] drop-shadow-2xl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>
                <p class="text-lg text-white font-medium drop-shadow-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, doloremque molestias itaque corporis exercitationem recusandae.</p>
                <div class="flex flex-row">
                    <a href="#" class="bg-transparent px-8 py-2 rounded-lg  text-white text-center border drop-shadow-md">Sign Up</a>
                    <a href="" class="bg-emerald-500 px-8 py-2 rounded-lg  text-white text-center drop-shadow-md">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </section>
```

`

I am unable to add any spacing for the elements inside the section. Beside the buttons within the div inside of the section. Where am I messing up?

I've tried adding the h1 and the p tag into their own div, changing which tag is the flex container and which is not, the sizing of the divs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working just fine.

```
<section id="introduction" class="h-[700px] bg-gradient-to-bl from-cyan-500 via-teal-400 to-blue-500">
  <div class="flex w-[450px] flex-col">
    <h1 class="text-6xl font-semibold leading-[75px] text-white drop-shadow-2xl p-8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>
    <p class="text-lg font-medium text-white drop-shadow-lg m-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, doloremque molestias itaque corporis exercitationem recusandae.</p>
    <div class="flex flex-row m-10">
      <a href="#" class="rounded-lg border bg-transparent px-8 py-2 text-center text-white drop-shadow-md mx-10">Sign Up</a>
      <a href="" class="rounded-lg bg-emerald-500 px-8 py-2 text-center text-white drop-shadow-md">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Output:

[image]

Code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/3SiMCCmHmR